# Listen to Yourself

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

<sub>*Part of the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/fortnightly-topic-challenge-35-restricted-title-1)*</sub>

---

[image]

What you'll have when you're finished is what you'll say once you're finished.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ABE IGNORE OUIJA NICE MAIDEN LIT

> A big Norwegian ice-made inlet = *F**J**ORD*

SUMMARY BOXER ACE SIX FOUR WRECKS AMPLE

> Some Reeboks or ASICS, for example = *SH**OE**S* (credit to [noedne](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66703/listen-to-yourself/66706#66706))

MISSED TERM US STIRRED INCLUDE DOUGH

> Mister Mustard in Cluedo = *CO**L**ONEL*

WAIT TROUPER REGIONS ACE MAUL

> Way true Parisians say small = *PET**IT***

THOUGH CINCH URCHIN ACING INGREW PAR

> Those in church in a singing group are...  = ***CH***OIR

DUPE PRESS INTENSE

> Do present tense = *D**OE**S* (credit to [noedne](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66703/listen-to-yourself/66706#66706))

JOELITCHOE

> J + OE + L + IT + CH + OE are each pronounced abnormally in the above words, as {y}+{oo}+{r}+{ee}+{k}+{uh}. (Not proper IPA, but should give the idea.)
>  Pronouncing them the same way in order here gives the final answer: we say **EUREKA**

Comment: lol, a suprising red herring of an answer, but wrong! :0

Comment: Ah, fixed my final answer now. I prefer this one to my original one, since some of the letters weren't actually silent. Nice puzzle, @stacksfiller!

Comment: +1 For saving me from repeating what I thought was a final Mad Gab.

Comment: Now it's right, even with the other one not technically working, I'm surprised how closely it worked.

Comment: Many Peeing Cats